# I have created a pub/sub model using @nestjs-plus/rabbitmq library but not being able to send acknowledgement from subscriber to publisher

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I have used `@RabbitSubscribe()` decorator for subscription and `AmqpConnection.publish()` for publisher and Pub/Sub is working properly. But I want acknowledgement back from subscriber to publisher when message will be delivered.

I expect the publisher should receive acknowledgement from subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer, you need to use RPC Handlers.

Send message:

```
const requestOptions: RequestOptions = {
    payload: {foo: 'bar'},
    exchange: 'exchange1',
    routingKey: 'rpc-route'
};
const result = await this.amqpConnection.request(requestOptions);
```

Message handling and response:

```
@RabbitRPC({
    exchange: 'exchange1',
    routingKey: 'rpc-route',
    queue: 'rpc-queue'
})
public async rpcHandler(msg: {}) {
    return {
        response: 42
    };
}
```